# VirtualBox Local Disk not recognizing Hard Drive space

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, virtualbox

I just have a VirtualBox running Windows 10 and I needed to expand it's hard drive disk space so I ran the following command:

```
VBoxManage modifyhd --resize 22500 ~/"VirtualBox VMs"/"Windows 10"/"Windows 10.vdi"
```

And, when I went into the specs of the VirtualBox, the space had expanded (which is good!), but I then tried decompressing a file in the VirtualBox and it threw an error saying that the disk had the original amount of space (and that I have insufficient space to decompress the file). When I checked the Local Drive to confirm, it did in fact not change.  How do I get the Local Drive to recognize the additional space?

**Note:** I cannot scrap the OS

**EDIT**

Solution, courtesy of @Ramhound.

I expanded the volume on the host OS but not the guest OS. So, in Windows, the space was just considered unallocated. I had to go into Disk Management in Windows and extend the volume. Here's the outline of how to do that: https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-open-disk-management-2626080

Comment: You expanded the virtual HDD but did you extend the partition from within Windows?  Simply making the virtual HDD larger isn’t enough.

Comment: @Ramhound you're right! That was it

Comment: @RyanCocuzzo More precisely explained: You expanded the virtual hard disk size but the Windows partition and the file system on it remained in the original size. --- Could you please add the answer as an answer below instead of editing it into the question?